Question About Definition of Hereditarily $\kappa$ Sets
In Kunen's "The Foundations of Mathematics," for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ we define $H(\kappa) = \{x\in WF: |\text{trcl}(x)|< \kappa\}$. I'm a little confused, because the cardinality of $\text{trcl}(x)$ is only defined if it is well-orderable. Are we assuming AC throughout, so that every set is well-orderable? Or are we perhaps just saying $H(\kappa)$ is the set of well-founded sets $x$ such that trcl(x) is well-orderable AND $|\text{trcl(x)}| < \kappa$?
Finally, how do we know that $H(\kappa)$ is in general a set and not a proper class? Thanks!

Yes. Kunen is assuming choice. Otherwise the definition gets more... Weird, perhaps, or at least much more complicated.

That $H(\kappa)$ is a set is not completely trivial, but there is an exercise (with hint) just below the definition. Also note despite the occasional wishy-washiness where "(using the axiom of choice)" is called out explicitly, just cracking the book and glancing at the text nearby, I already see a couple other statements that require AC without this attribution e.g. "show that $R(\gamma)$ is a model of ZC".

Adding from Asaf's comment, my impression is that without choice there is no guarantee that we have a version of $H_\kappa$ satisfying the Axiom of Collection for a regular $\kappa$.

Comment by Asaf Karagila answers question about AC and here is what I believe is a solution to the second question following the exercise as suggested by spaceisdarkgreen.
We show that $H(\kappa) \subseteq R(\kappa)$. Let $x\in H(\kappa)$ and define $\gamma = \{\text{rank}(z): z\in \text{trcl}(x)\}$. Then $\gamma\in ON$ and $|\gamma| \leq |\text{trcl}(x)| < \kappa$, implying $\gamma < \kappa$. Then if $z\in x\subseteq \text{trcl(x)}$ we have $\text{rank}(z) < \gamma$ and so
$$
\text{rank}(x) = \sup\{\text{rank}(z)+1 : z\in x\} \leq \gamma.
$$
Then we have $\text{rank}(x) < \gamma +1 < \kappa$ (the second inquality because $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and hence a limit ordinal) and so $x\in R(\gamma +1) \subseteq R(\kappa)$.
